# what is the best way to scrape multiple domains with scrapy?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I have around 10 odd sites that I wish to scrape from. A couple of them are wordpress blogs and they follow the same html structure, albeit with different classes. The others are either forums or blogs of other formats.

The information I like to scrape is common - the post content, the timestamp, the author, title and the comments.

My question is, do i have to create one separate spider for each domain? If not, how can I create a generic spider that allows me scrape by loading options from a configuration file or something similar?

I figured I could load the xpath expressions from a file which location can be loaded via command line but there seems to be some difficulties when scraping for some domain requires that I use regex `select(expression_here).re(regex)` while some do not.

Answer (score 3):

At scrapy spider set the allowed_domains to a list of domains for example :

```
class YourSpider(CrawlSpider):    
   allowed_domains = [ 'domain1.com','domain2.com' ]
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Well I faced the same issue so I created the spider class dynamically using `type()`,

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
import urlparse

class GenericSpider(CrawlSpider):
    """a generic spider, uses type() to make new spider classes for each domain"""
    name = 'generic'
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = []

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, link):
        domain = urlparse.urlparse(link).netloc.lower()
        # generate a class name such that domain www.google.com results in class name GoogleComGenericSpider
        class_name = (domain if not domain.startswith('www.') else domain[4:]).title().replace('.', '') + cls.__name__
        return type(class_name, (cls,), {
            'allowed_domains': [domain],
            'start_urls': [link],
            'name': domain
        })
```

So say, to create a spider for 'http://www.google.com' I'll just do -

```
In [3]: google_spider = GenericSpider.create('http://www.google.com')

In [4]: google_spider
Out[4]: __main__.GoogleComGenericSpider

In [5]: google_spider.name
Out[5]: 'www.google.com'
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I do sort of the same thing using the following XPath expressions:

- `'/html/head/title/text()'` for the title
- `//p[string-length(text()) > 150]/text()` for the post content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a empty `allowed_domains` attribute to instruct scrapy not to filter any offsite request. But in that case you must be careful and only return relevant requests from your spider.

Answer (score 0):

You should use BeautifulSoup especially if you're using Python. It enables you to find elements in the page, and extract text using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use start_request method!

and then you can prioritize each url as well!
And then on top of that you can pass some meta data!

Here's a sample code that works:

```
"""
For allowed_domains:
Let’s say your target url is https://www.example.com/1.html, 
then add 'example.com' to the list.
"""
class crawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = "crawler_name"

    allowed_domains, urls_to_scrape = parse_urls()
    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=['.*']),
             callback='parse_item',
             follow=True)
        ]
    def start_requests(self):
        for i,url in enumerate(self.urls_to_scrape):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url.strip(),callback=self.parse_item, priority=i+1, meta={"pass_anydata_hare":1})

    def parse_item(self, response):
        response = response.css('logic')

        yield {'link':str(response.url),'extracted data':[],"meta_data":'data you passed' }
```

I recommend you to read this page for more info at scrapy

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests

Hope this helps :)